# Will StoreKit2 have breaking changes?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, storekit

I cannot find any relevant information about the impact of StoreKit2. On some sites I read statements like

> There’s a new server API, which marks the end of /verifyReceipt

[source](https://www.revenuecat.com/blog/storekit-2-overview/#:%7E:text=There%E2%80%99s%20a%20new%20server%20API%2C%20which%20marks%20the%20end%20of%C2%A0/verifyReceipt)

But I cannot find any official statement from Apple about deprecation or even disabling an endpoint.

**Will StoreKit2 contain mandatory changes? Will endpoints like `verifyReceipt` be still working once StoreKit2 and the corresponding App Store API updates are released?**

Comment: StoreKit2 doesn't have *breaking changes* since it is an entirely new API that operates alongside the original store kit.  What you are asking is will Apple "turn off" the old one.  StoreKit2 is *already released*.  You can use it today.  StoreKit2 is easier to use and StoreKit2 will receive enhancements while the original StoreKit will not.  I can't see Apple turning off the original Store Kit soon as there would be hundreds of thousands of apps in the store that depend on it.  They may announce end of life for it at some point, but as yet they have not.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to this because I googled for breaking changes - Apple has never announced turning off an endpoint or anything like that HOWEVER the way their endpoints respond on iOS 16 and watchOS 9 seem to have changed and seem to very well break some implementations.

Coming from [StoreKit 2: `try await Product.products` does not finish and does not throw. Can watchOS fetch products on TestFlight builds? iOS works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73762555/storekit-2-try-await-product-products-does-not-finish-and-does-not-throw-can) with a lot of people in https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit/issues/682 having the same problem.

It feels like a bug on Apple's side but unfortunately we cannot tell for sure.